# Encrypt & Decrypt Local Images in Windows Store App

Tags: c#, encryption, windows-store-apps, base64, windows-8.1

I'm building a Windows Store App including a local folder of Images.

I want to protect all the Images so they can't be accessed from:

```
C:\Users[username]\AppData\Local\Packages\LocalState\Settings\settings.dat
```

I know I should encrypt and decrypt the Images using the `DataProtectionProvider` class, but the documentation only shows how to encrypt/decrypt strings...

How should I convert a Bitmap image into a byte array? or should I encode it with `Base64`? Is there any tutorial or sample using this process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easiest if the images you want to encrypt are loaded from files and written back out to files. Then you can do:

```
async void EncryptFile(IStorageFile fileToEncrypt, IStorageFile encryptedFile)
{
    IBuffer buffer = await FileIO.ReadBufferAsync(fileToEncrypt);

    DataProtectionProvider dataProtectionProvider = 
        new DataProtectionProvider(ENCRYPTION_DESCRIPTOR);

    IBuffer encryptedBuffer = 
        await dataProtectionProvider.ProtectAsync(buffer);

    await FileIO.WriteBufferAsync(encryptedFile, encryptedBuffer);
}
```

`DataProtectionProvider.ProtectStreamAsync` is another alternative if you can get stream instances from your inputs and outputs. For example, if you have a `byte[]` containing your image data then you can create an in-memory input stream from it:

```
byte[] imageData = ...
using (var inputMemoryStream = new MemoryStream(imageData).AsInputStream())
{
    ...
}
```

**Edit:** Then for example to decrypt the file and display it in an `Image` control you could do:

```
var encryptedBuffer = await FileIO.ReadBufferAsync(encryptedFile);

var dataProtectionProvider = new DataProtectionProvider();

var buffer = await dataProtectionProvider.UnprotectAsync(encryptedBuffer);

var bmp = new BitmapImage();
await bmp.SetSourceAsync(buffer.AsStream().AsRandomAccessStream());
imageControl.Source = bmp;
```

Comment: What about the `encryptedFile`? It should be an image and it should be empty first... how do I initialize it? And about the `DecryptFile()` method, should I do the same using the `encryptedFile`, a new `decryptedFile`,  `UnprotectAsync` and `WriteBufferAsync` ?

Comment: @LayaleMatta You can initialize `encryptedFile` using any of the file/open APIs e.g. `var encryptedFile = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync(filename)`. And yup; I've added a decryption example to my answer above to show that.

Comment: I'm getting a `System.IO.FileNotFoundException` in the encryptFile method at `IBuffer buffer = await FileIO.ReadBufferAsync(fileToEncrypt);`  I have the right path thought, and the image do exist in the local folder that I am mentioning. This is the path to fileToEncrypt: `"C:\\[...]\\Projects\\eBookApp\\eBookApp\\bin\\Debug\\AppX\\\\Assets\\Images\\page1.jpg"`

Comment: You have 4 backslashes between AppX and Assets, perhaps that is the problem. Otherwise double check the path is definitely correct and/or try with another image somewhere else.

Comment: Also, a more correct way to load an image from assets would be to do: `var fileToEncrypt = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/Images/page1.jpg"));`. You may get an `UnauthorizedAccessException` otherwise.

Comment: It worked, it was my string path `@"\Assets\Images\page"` instead of `@"Assets\Images\page"`. I am returning `var buffer = await dataProtectionProvider.UnprotectAsync(protectedBuffer);` from my `public async Task<IBuffer> DecryptFile(IStorageFile encryptedFile)` method. But when I call the `DecryptFile` method like this:  `IBuffer buffer = await DecryptFile(encryptedFile);` I get a  `'System.ArgumentException'`

Comment: What line specifically throws the `ArgumentException`?

Comment: `IBuffer buffer = await DecryptFile(encryptedFile);`

Comment: Post the entire `DecryptFile` method and/or put a breakpoint in it and step through until you find the line that throws `ArgumentException`.

Comment: I've posted my functions as a new answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
        public async void Protect()
        {
            for (int i = 1; i < 24; i++)
            {
                string imageFile = ImagePages[i];
                var fileToEncrypt = await Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFileAsync(imageFile);
                var encryptedFile1 = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync("encryptedPage" + i);

                var encryptedFile2 = await EncryptFile(fileToEncrypt, encryptedFile1);
                IBuffer buffer = await DecryptFile(encryptedFile2);
                //(2.) It goes here and throw the 'System.ArgumentException' having the encryptedFile's ContentType=""

                var bmp = new BitmapImage();
                await bmp.SetSourceAsync(buffer.AsStream().AsRandomAccessStream());

                //Fill the List responsible for the Portrait View
                MyPortrait mp = new MyPortrait();
                mp.onlyImage = bmp;
                PImageList.Add(mp);
            }
        }    

        public async Task<IStorageFile> EncryptFile(IStorageFile fileToEncrypt, IStorageFile encryptedFile)
        {
            IBuffer buffer = await FileIO.ReadBufferAsync(fileToEncrypt);
            //I have no more exceptions here

            DataProtectionProvider dataProtectionProvider = new DataProtectionProvider("LOCAL=user");

            IBuffer encryptedBuffer = await dataProtectionProvider.ProtectAsync(buffer);
            //(1.) After arriving here when deploying it goes to (2.)

            await FileIO.WriteBufferAsync(encryptedFile, encryptedBuffer);

            return encryptedFile;
        }

        public async Task<IBuffer> DecryptFile(IStorageFile encryptedFile)
        {
            var protectedBuffer = await FileIO.ReadBufferAsync(encryptedFile);

            var dataProtectionProvider = new DataProtectionProvider();

            var buffer = await dataProtectionProvider.UnprotectAsync(protectedBuffer);

            return buffer;
        }
```

Comment: I suspect it's because you're trying to read from `encryptedFile` after having written to it in `EncryptFile`. Try re-opening the encrypted file with `GetFileAsync` before passing it to `DecryptFile`.

Comment: Exactly! I returned the encryptedFile from the EncryptFile method! Thank you! You rock @peterdn